# What does ても＋いかん do?

Tags: grammar, words

> 今闘技場にいる観衆は外に出すな、モンスターが脱走したことを悟られ**てもいかん**！

What meaning does いかん have in this sentence? I've never seen this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

いかん is short for いけない.

> Don't let the audiences in the arena go outside. It is not good if they notice the monsters have escaped.