# Weird Inflection -されていかん

Tags: dialects, passive-voice, modality, によって-passives

I am reading Alita Battle Angel, and I came across a sentence that I do understand, but for some reason is conjugated to the negative.  Please could someone break the sentence down for me?

> > (After becoming just your head, you have become rather talkative)
> >
> > 取｛と｝り憑{つ｝く体によって知能レベルがどうも　**左右{さゆう}されていかん…**
> >
> > (My intelligence is influenced by the body I possess...)

My understanding is that どうも gives the meaning of 'somewhat, fairly, quite', but I do not know why いかない is not in the plain form. Also, what does it do when the passive form of the main verb is used?

Comment: あかん (Kansai area) and いけん (Chuugoku region) are used similarly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

いかん in this sentence means "no good", "of no use", "it sucks", etc. It's adding the speaker's feeling about the mentioned fact (左右される). いかん is almost a lexicalized expression, and it is also used like English "oops", "don't do it" or "oh my gosh". It sounds a little pompous or dialectal.

Related:

- [What does ても＋いかん do?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28856/5010)
- [Meaning of いかんしょ in following sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28280/5010)
- [Use of "いかん" in the following sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61398/5010)